AWS Glue Job in a private VPC
I have a private RDS instance in a private VPC and I want to use a Glue ETL job to extract a table and save it to a private S3 bucket in parquet format.
I’ve successfully connected the job to my RDS instance — I confirmed this by launching a data preview session from the visual editor:

However, I’m unable to write data to S3, and I suspect it's a permission issue.
From the logs, I can see these lines:
2024-10-24T13:15:08.366Z Download bucket: aws-glue-assets-288647866680-eu-west-1 key: scripts/RDS Export.py with usingProxy: false

2024-10-24T13:19:09.004Z SdkClientException occurred : com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to aws-glue-assets-288647866680-eu-west-1.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:443 [aws-glue-assets-288647866680-eu-west-1.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/52.92.16.82, aws-glue-assets-288647866680-eu-west-1.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/52.218.93.120, aws-glue-assets-288647866680-eu-west-1.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/52.218.41.80, aws-glue-assets-288647866680-eu-west-1.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/3.5.66.31, aws-glue-assets-288647866680-eu-west-1.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/3.5.68.157, aws-glue-assets-288647866680-eu-west-1.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/52.218.0.216, aws-glue-assets-288647866680-eu-west-1.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/3.5.64.1, aws-glue-assets-288647866680-eu-west-1.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/3.5.64.176] failed: connect timed out
3 Retry(s) left

The file aws-glue-assets-288647866680-eu-west-1/scripts/RDS Export.py is the ETL job script. Each retry without a proxy fails, while the first try with the proxy succeeds.
2024-10-24T13:30:59.977Z Download bucket: aws-glue-assets-288647866680-eu-west-1 key: scripts/RDS Export-copy.py with usingProxy: true
2024-10-24T13:30:59.980Z INFO 2024-10-24T13:30:59,980 1003217 com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient [main] Configuring Proxy. Proxy Host: 169.254.76.0 Proxy Port: 8888
2024-10-24T13:31:00.267Z Launching ...

The script then starts, but nothing is written to S3.
I have the following resources:

A vpc (vpc-1) with 3 subnets (private-subnet, public-subnet, database-subnet). Both the Glue job and the RDS instance reside in the database-subnet.
A VPC Endpoint of type Gateway for the service "com.amazonaws.my-region.s3" attached to all route tables of vpc-1 (route-table-private-subnet, route-table-public-subnet, route-table-database-subnet).
A security group (sg-1) associated with vpc-1, with both inbound and outbound rules of type All TCP, protocol TCP, ip range 0 - 65535 and source/destination set to the security group itself (sg-1)
A data connection (pgsql-conn-1), connector type JDBC, subnet database-subnet, security group (sg-1), with username and password
A network ACL with the following inbound and outbound rules:

Allow: rule number: 100, type: All traffic, protocol: All, port range: All, source/destination: 0.0.0.0/0, Allow
Allow: rule number: 101, type: All traffic, protocol: All, port range: All, source/destination: ::/0, Allow
Allow: rule number: -, type: All traffic, protocol: All, port range: All, source/destination: 0.0.0.0/0, Deny


A RDSExportRole with the following policies:

AWS managed policy: AmazonRDSReadOnlyAccess
AWS managed policy: AmazonS3FullAccess
AWS managed policy: AWSGlueServiceRole
Customer inline policy with: "Statement": [ { "Sid": "Statement1", "Effect": "Allow", "Action": [ "iam:PassRole" ], "Resource": [ "arn:aws:iam::aws_account_id:role/RDSExportRole" ] } ]



Any insights on why the write to S3 might be failing would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Connection timed out suggests network path issue rather than permissions typically. Ideally you would use the default network ACLs (and maybe you are, just want to alert you to double-check them if you modified them). Do you have DNS support and DNS hostnames enabled for the VPC? Other considerations here.

Consider granting the role access to the bucket through the bucket’s permission settings. I resolved a similar issue this way in the past.
